# How can i import ms word document content to ReactJS component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, npm, ms-word

I searched for the answer, but only found how to export to ms word.

I need to have button on my page that let me find file in file system and paste its content to ReactJs text editor component.

Is there any React module to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the file's content on the backend. For example with Streamreader class with C#.Net or with the fs module in node.js. Then you can send the data for your frontend.

Comment: Thanks. Forget about thing, that front doesn't have access to file system.